# Using alex/happy with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, happy, alex

I'm writing a compiler for a class I'm taking. The class isn't specifically Haskell but I'm using Haskell to write my compiler and interpreter. I have a cabal package setup to hopefully make it easy for my prof to run/compile.

I have happy and alex in the `build-tools` field for both executables but Cabal ignores that and then complains that it cannot find the modules that Happy and Alex should be generating.

If I manually run:

```
alex LimpScanner.x
happy LimpParser.y
```

then cabal runs perfectly.

I thought I had cabal automatically running them earlier but perhaps I remember imperfectly.

### Contents of `limp.cabal`:

```
Name:                limp
Version:             0.1
Synopsis:            LIMP Compiler (Compiler Construction course project)
Homepage:            http://www.cs.rit.edu/~eca7215/limp/
License:             AllRightsReserved
License-file:        LICENSE
Author:              Edward Amsden
Maintainer:          eca7215@cs.rit.edu
Category:            Language
Build-type:          Simple
Cabal-version:       >=1.2

Executable limp
  -- .hs or .lhs file containing the Main module.
  Main-is: Limp.hs

  hs-source-dirs: src     
  
  -- Packages needed in order to build this package.
  Build-depends: base, array, haskell98     
  
  -- Modules not exported by this package.
  -- Other-modules:       
  
  -- Extra tools (e.g. alex, hsc2hs, ...) needed to build the source.
  Build-tools:         alex, happy
Executable limpi
  Main-is: LimpInterpreter.hs
  hs-source-dirs: src
  Build-depends: base, array, haskell98
  Build-tools: alex, happy
```

### Directory layout:

```
limp/
├── Setup.hs
├── limp.cabal
└── src/
    ├── Limp.hs
    ├── LimpInterpreter.hs
    ├── LimpParser.ly
    ├── LimpScanner.x
    └── LimpToken.hs
```

Comment: As long as you state that you use modules `LimpParser` and `LimpScanner`, have files named `LimpParser.x` and `LimpScanner.ly`, and have Alex and Happy installed, then any Cabal version from the last year or so should have automatically run `alex` and `happy`.  Hmm.

Comment: We need more details. What is your directory layout? What is your cabal file?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be the other way around? LimpParser.ly and LimpScanner.x?

Comment: Edited to add .cabal file and directory layout

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently what I was missing was actually the Other-modules: field. Once this was added, cabal happily (pardon the pun) built my interpreter.

Comment: Good on you for answering this yourself.

Comment: Could you complete the example and show what Other-modules should be set to? Thanks,

Answer (score 19):

For Warren Harris and others like him (and myself) that may come along later, other-modules needs to be set to a list of module names that (I guess?) are expected to be built by the tools listed in build-tools.

So, in my case, the relevant sections of my .cabal file ended up looking like this:

```
build-tools:         alex, happy
other-modules:       Language.Heidi.Parser,
                     Language.Heidi.Lexer
```

Comment: Note: use build-tool-depends: alex:alex (build-tools is deprecated/removed since cabal 2/3).